# Sails fails to return or error on large result set

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I am bypassing the ORM and using the Model.query function to query and return a "large" result set from PostgreSQL. The query returns around 2 million rows. When running the query directly from postgres it returns in around 20s. The query fails silently when executed from sails. Is there a limit on the number of rows that can be returned?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit on the number of rows that can be returned?

No there is no limit.

> The query fails silently when executed from sails

What does "fails silently" mean? How do you know that it's failed? It may still be processing; or the adapter might have a connection timeout that you're breaching.

Two million rows serialized out of the database, translated to JSON, and piped down to the client is *much* different than just running SQL directly on the database. It could take 20x longer, depending on your system resource situation. I strongly recommend using sails.js's paging features to pull the data out in chunks. Pulling two million rows in one operation from a web server doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Fails silently as in I do not see a time out or any other error in the console.

Comment: Thanks I know what fails silently *means*. How long did you wait? 2 million rows is a lot of rows. You're missing the point, and probably need to re-read my answer.